# Automapper v8 is not ignoring navigation properties of EF (Entity Framework) class

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, automapper

Below is the code for Automapper profile:

```
public class MyMappingProfile: Profile
{
    public MyMappingProfile()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<MyModelClass, MyEntityClass>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.NavigationProp1, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.NavigationProp2, opt => opt.Ignore());
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the code for creating a new entity object (FYI, I am using this code in .NET Core project, so _mapper is the :

```
var newEntity = _mapper.Map<MyModelClass, MyEntityClass>(model);
```

But the above code line produce the below error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>
> ## For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
>   MyModelClass -> MyEntityClass (Destination member list)
>   MyModelClass -> MyEntityClass (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>
> NavigationProp1
>
> NavigationProp2

Any idea why Automapper is still complaining for unmapped members even after they are ignored?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the defination for `MyModelClass` and `MyEntityClass `? Share us related code, mini demo would be helpful.

Comment: You're not configuring it correctly. See [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core).

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu, can you please point out what exactly I am doing wrong in configuration? I went through the link you provided, but couldn't figure out the misconfigurtion. Thanks.

Comment: Start from scratch with a simple test as in the docs. Make that work. And then you'll see the difference.

Comment: Due to time constraint, I can't spend much time on this. So I have added both the missing destination properties into source, and this has resolved the problem for now. Thanks to all for their suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it resolved by changing the mapping profile class as below:

```
public class MyMappingProfile: Profile
{
    public MyMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MyModelClass, MyEntityClass>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NavigationProp1, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NavigationProp2, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

Cheers.